# Multiple Tomcat Processes, due to NIO?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Because we are using WebSocket, we asked our Sysadmin to re-configure our Tomcat (tomcat7) instances to run with NIO (as per [Apache's recommendation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html)).

Shortly thereafter, Sysadmin reported that there are 3 instances of tomcat itself, and each process is a child of the **root** process.  He seems to think that this is a problem, and one that is caused by our applications (we have 2 web apps / WARs).  While it's true that our applications are under development and not without bugs, I highly doubt that we suddenly and accidentally managed to implement multi-processing.

Rather, I think that this may simply be an implementation detail of NIO, but it's very unclear.  NIO seems to explicitly involve more clever *thread* management, but I cannot seem to turn up any documentation or commentary on it using multi-processing to do so.  Does anyone know if this is 'working as designed'?  Should I expect **exactly** 3 processes?

Comment: Are they JVM processes or just the wrapper script launching them?

Comment: Well 3 processes of same tomcat instance are quite unlikely. Still we need to know how your tomcat process is started or stopped, is there any init script for that or you are using `startup.sh` script only. Is your tomcat configured to create a **PID** file in *catalina home* or any where else. Using a pid file is good idea, as it can prevent the start  of multiple tomcat processes if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blerg - I think the answer is nothing so exotic.  After prodding Sysadmin more, I believe that all we're seeing is instances stacking up upon re-deploy--and failure of running instances to fully shut down.